# Return LocalForage Promise

Tags: angularjs, localforage

I was wondering how I would return the `token` key in this query

```
 function inspectionResource($resource, $localForage) {
    return $resource("https://blah.org.uk/inspection/v1/:fieldofficernumber/booked", {fieldofficernumber:'@fieldofficernumber'}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'get',
            isArray: true,
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localForage.getItem("token") }
        }
    });
}
```

Im not sure how to use the `.then(function(value){}` in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return localForage.getItem("token").then(function (token) {
  return $resource(...);
});
```